# Does memcpy work for large arrays in structures?

Tags: arrays, memcpy

I have a structure that has a dynamic array in it. I have defined two of these structures.

I fill the array in the first structure, then use a line like

memcpy(R->v, A->v, A->n*sizeof(double)

where v is the array that has been dynamically allocated, and n is the number of entries.

R and A are the same type if that matters.

The problem is, the values are not being properyl copied into R. Any idea why? When I try to debug this in totalview, memcpy goes into a function called "very_huge_loop", but no exception or anything is thrown.

the array is approx 188k doubles in length.

Thanks

Comment: memcpy should work fine for the situation you describe, although you have missed out some details that may shed more light (the types of the arrays, are they the same size? Have you allocated enough memory in both to hold n*8 bytes? etc). It's possible that it's working ok and the debugger is showing you incorrect values (e.g. if you're debugging a release build, it may not be able to visualise the values correctly). Also check that A->v contains the correct values before the copy - perhaps something is corrupting it before you even do the copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be memory alignment.  Some architectures do not like multi-byte values like `double` to start on any arbitrary byte address.  When you allocate the array memory, you  might want to use a function like `memalign()` instead of `malloc()`.  If you are using `new double[n]` then it should already be aligned correctly.